# In image processing, what is real time?

Tags: image-processing, real-time

in image processing applications what is considered real time? Is 33 fps real time? Is 20 fps real time? If 33 and 20 fps are considered real time then is 1 or 2 fps also real time?

Can anyone throw some light.

Comment: That's right Joe. I have an Embedded Processing platform connected with a camera and my algorithm can process only ~1 fps, so, can I still consider this as real time?

Comment: In computer graphics >20 fps can be considered as *real time*, because it starts looking fluent. At >5 fps it is often called *interactive* (like in CAD programs), so at 1-2 fps I think you could call it that to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, it's a pretty vague term. Often, what is meant is that the algorithm will run at the rate of the source (e.g. a camera) supplying the images; however, I would prefer to state this explicitly ("the algorithm can process images at the frame rate of the camera").

Answer (score 7):

**Real time image processing = produce output simultaneously with the input.**

The input may be 25 fps but you may choose to process 1 of every 5 frames(that makes 5 fps processing) and your application is still real time.

TV streaming software: all the frames are processed.

Security application and the input is CCTV security cams: you may choose to skip some frames to fit the performance.

3d game or simulation: fps changes depending on the current scene.

And they are all real time.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, I would say real-time means that the application is generating images *based on user input as it occurs*, e.g. a mouse movement which changes the facing of an avatar.

How *successful* it is at this task - 1 fps, 10 fps, 100 fps, etc - is actually another question.

Real-time describes an *approach*, not a performance metric.

If however you ask what is the slowest fps which passes as usable by a human, the answer is about 15, I think.

Answer (score 2):

i think it depends on what the real time application is.  If the app is showing slideshows with 1 picture every 3 seconds, and the app can process 1 picture within this 3 seconds and show it, then it is real time processing.

If the movie is 29.97 frames per second, and the app can process all 29.97 frames within the second, then it is also real time.

An example is, if an app can take the movie from a VCR or Cable's analog output, and compress it into 29.97 frames per second video and also send all that info to a remote area for another person to watch, then it is real time processing.

Answer (score 2):

(Hard) Real time is when an outcome has no value when delivered too early or too late.

Any FPS is real time provided that displayed frames represent what should be displayed at the very instant they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of real-time display is not really tied to a specific frame rate - it could be defined as the *minimum frame rate at which movement is perceived as being continuous*. So for slow moving objects in a visual frame (e.g. ships in a harbour, or stars in the night sky) a relatively slow frame rate might suffice, whereas for rapid movement (e.g. a racing car simulator) a much higher frame rate would be needed.

There is also a secondary consideration of *latency*. A real-time display must have sufficiently low latency in relation to other events (e.g. behaviour of a real-time simulation) that there is no perceptible lag in display updates.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually an easy question (even without taking into account differences between individulas).

Wikipedia  has a [good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate#How_many_frames_per_second_can_the_human_eye_see.3F) explaining why. For what it's worth, I think cinema films run at 24fps so, if you're happy with that, that's what I'd consider realtime.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to do.  For some purposes 1fps or even 2 spf (Seconds per frame) could be considered real-time.  For others thats way too slow ...

That said, real-time means that it takes as long (or less) to process x frames as it would take to just present those x frames.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

- automatic aircraft cannon - 1000 fps
- monitoring - 10 - 15 fps
- authentication - 1 fps
- medical devices - 1 fph

Comment: Medical devices don't produce 1 fph. Even some MRI sequences produce up to two images per second (e.g. bSSFP).

Comment: @Corbie It does not matter. What matters is how fast do you need to process images not how fast something produce it.

Comment: In interventional MRI applications you do need medical images as fast as possible. You don't want to stick a needle in a patient and wait an hour for an image to know if you hit the target.

Comment: @Corbie In that case is always human. In other cases it does not matter.

Comment: The question was "what is real time", so stating how fast different imaging modalities are does not answer the question. Real time medical imaging is way faster.

Comment: @Corbie Image processing <> image displaying. Real-time programs must guarantee response within specified time constraints, often referred to as "deadlines".  Write software detecting SCC from body scan under 1h better than human. Samsung will pay you millions of dollars next day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the term is used with different meanings in different contexts. In industrial image processing, real time processing is usually the opposite of offline processing. In offline processing applications, you record images (many of them) and process them at a later time. In real time processing, the system that acquires the images also processes them, at the same time, so the processing frame rate must not be higher than the acquisition frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time means your implementation is fast enough to meet some deadline.  The deadline is part of your system's specification.  If it's an interactive UI and the users are not too picky, 15Hz update can be OK, although it can feel laggy.  If you're using it to drive a car along the motorway 30Hz is about right.  If it's a missile, well, maybe 100Hz?